# My app is not showing in IOS Share menu. Share extensions seems to be working but it's not showing m app

Tags: ios, flutter, share

I have integrated share extension in Flutter. its working on android and on IOS. The problem I m having is my app isn't showing in IOS share menu

I have used apple documentations and Flutter documentations. Multiple times and projects. However none of them are showing in share menu. It works on android.
I tested on Simulators and on Real iPhone 12 and iPhone 7 but my app didn't appeared.

IOS Version: 17
Target for both Extension and app: 14

There is no console error or warning I tried Verbose as well. Looks like misconfiguration.
I verified group and identifier multiple times those are all same. If I run extension from xcode it run successfully but nothing shows up.

Wasted my 6Days on this. Anyone to help me out?

I tried restarting iphone and mac, I have tried change activation rules, I have tried to create multiple new projects and extensions but none of them worked.

My app should appear for Urls/text

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.